# Getting maximum mins for each category of column in a dataframe using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 5 columns.  Now I need to get maximum minutes for each category of the name. I tried the below approach but I need to group by each time for each category of columns.  Is there any better way to get the result in one single step instead of grouping multiple times?

```
 val customers = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Alice", "abc","cat1","pt1", 50.00),
                                ("Alice", "abc","cat1","pt1", 45.00),
                                ("Alice", "bcd","cat2","pt1", 55.00),
                                ("Bob", "abc","cat1","pt4", 25.00),
                                ("Bob", "bcd","cat1","pt4", 29.00),
                                ("Bob", "av","cat4","pt4",27.00))).toDF("name","nw","cat","pt","min")


val wSpec1 = Window.partitionBy("name","nw").orderBy("min")
val wSpec2 = Window.partitionBy("name","cat").orderBy("min")    
val wSpec3 = Window.partitionBy("name","pt").orderBy("min") 

val test1 = customers.withColumn("sumnt",sum(customers("min")).over(wSpec1))
val test2 = customers.withColumn("sumct",sum(customers("min")).over(wSpec2))
val test3 = customers.withColumn("sumpt",sum(customers("min")).over(wSpec3))

val data1 = test1.groupBy("name","nw").agg(max($"sumnt"))
val data2 = test2.groupBy("name","cat").agg(max($"sumct"))
val data3 = test3.groupBy("name","pt").agg(max($"sumpt"))


val res =     data1.join(data2,Seq("name"),"left").join(data3,Seq("name"),"left")

+-----+---+-----------+
| name| nw|max(sumnt)|
+-----+---+-----------+
|Alice|bcd|       55.0|
|  Bob| av|       27.0|
|  Bob|bcd|       29.0|
|Alice|abc|       95.0|
|  Bob|abc|       25.0|
+-----+---+-----------+
```

After doing individual and join, I will get the result as below

```
+-----+---+----------+----+----------+---+----------+
| name| nw|max(sumnt)| cat|max(sumct)| pt|max(sumpt)|
+-----+---+----------+----+----------+---+----------+
|Alice|bcd|      55.0|cat1|      95.0|pt1|     150.0|
|Alice|bcd|      55.0|cat2|      55.0|pt1|     150.0|
|Alice|abc|      95.0|cat1|      95.0|pt1|     150.0|
|Alice|abc|      95.0|cat2|      55.0|pt1|     150.0|
|  Bob| av|      27.0|cat1|      54.0|pt4|      81.0|
|  Bob| av|      27.0|cat4|      27.0|pt4|      81.0|
|  Bob|bcd|      29.0|cat1|      54.0|pt4|      81.0|
|  Bob|bcd|      29.0|cat4|      27.0|pt4|      81.0|
|  Bob|abc|      25.0|cat1|      54.0|pt4|      81.0|
|  Bob|abc|      25.0|cat4|      27.0|pt4|      81.0|
+-----+---+----------+----+----------+---+----------+
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share the expected dataframe too?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Are you sure about the output dataframe you have provided? The numbers don't add up.

Comment: that might be a mistake,but the logic is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
  var lst = List("nw", "cat", "pt")
  lst.foreach {
    col =>
      var window = Window.partitionBy("name", col)
      customers = customers.withColumn("sum_" + col, sum($"min").over(window))
      customers = customers.withColumn("max_" + col, max(customers.col("sum_" + col)).over(window))
      customers = customers.drop("sum_" + col)
  }
  customers.show
```

It will generate the following output.

```
+-----+---+----+---+----+------+-------+------+
| name| nw| cat| pt| min|max_nw|max_cat|max_pt|
+-----+---+----+---+----+------+-------+------+
|  Bob| av|cat4|pt4|27.0|  27.0|   27.0|  81.0|
|  Bob|bcd|cat1|pt4|29.0|  29.0|   54.0|  81.0|
|  Bob|abc|cat1|pt4|25.0|  25.0|   54.0|  81.0|
|Alice|bcd|cat2|pt1|55.0|  55.0|   55.0| 150.0|
|Alice|abc|cat1|pt1|45.0|  95.0|   95.0| 150.0|
|Alice|abc|cat1|pt1|50.0|  95.0|   95.0| 150.0|
+-----+---+----+---+----+------+-------+------+
```